# How to create a keyboard shortcut to a fullscreen window?

Tags: keyboard, desktop, spaces, mission-control

When a window is fullscreen, it occupies a new Desktop in Mission Control. Is there a way to have a keyboard shortcut to got to that desktop/space (without having to recreate the shortcut each time)?

Context: Zoom tends to occupy this desktop. I tend to have 9 desktops and have set it so that Mission Control doesn't rearrange them. This means that Zoom will occupy the 10th desktop.

Comment: What macOS version are you using? if you are on macOS 12 or above, you can use the shortcuts app to add a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: A full-screened window occupies a new Space, not a maximized one.

Comment: @MarcWilson - I've corrected that in the question, as it makes a huge amount of difference to the potential answer. [I personally don't know of any way other than Ctrl/highest number (in this case 9) then Ctrl right arrow; another of the many reasons I never use fullscreen.]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the application that is full-screened, and it's the only one, do this:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "application_name"' -e 'activate' -e 'end tell'
```

That will switch to the application.